# Bluetooth device does not respond to LESetScanParameters and LESetScanEnable

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

As part of a BLE logging project, I use an Arduino device (Adafruit Feather 32u4 Adalogger) in conjunction with a BLE-Central-capable Bluetooth device (RedBearLab BLEMini, using Texas Instruments CC2540 MCU) with the Host-Controller-Interface (HCI) passthrough firmware.

The general idea is to set the device to record LE advertising packets (as LE Advertising Repots) to an SD card. The device should run 24/7.

So far, the set-up works well right up until `LESetScanParameters`, where the BLEMini never responds to the command sent by the state machine on the Arduino. This is actually also true for the `LESetScanEnable` command which should be sent just after that. The Bluetooth core specification specifically says that both `LESetScanParameters (0x200b)` and `LESetScanEnable (0x200c)` commands should cause a `CommandComplete (0x0e)` event in response, carrying the return status of said commands (Refer to the Bluetooth core specification v4.2, pages 861, 977, and 980).

Why am I not getting a response? What am I missing? Many thanks for any help on that matter!

The system is currently designed as a state machine.

You can see the debug output just below, where `->` signifies a state transition (possibly followed by a message after the colon `:`). The raw HCI packets being sent (`Send: [...]`) and received (`Receive: [...]`) always start with a varying-length header (bytes separated by colons `:`, terminated by a pound `#`) and are followed by the packet body. Upon receiving an event in every `Await` state, the most significant parameters are printed.

Notice in the debug output below that the state `Await LESetScanParameters CommandComplete` terminates with a timeout error, stating that the packet header is incomplete. In fact, if you look at the line just below (`buffer [...]`), you see that no bytes were in the serial buffer. Even if I disable the timeout (e.g. wait for half an hour), I never receive a response. I also tried sending a malformed `LESetScanParameters` packet, and leaving out the commands `GapDeviceInit`, `SetEventMask` and `LESetEventMask`, but that didn't change anything.

My settings for the `LESetScanParameters` command are:

```
scanType = PassiveScan (0x00)
scanInterval = 0x0010
scanWindow = 0x0010
addressType = PublicIdentityAddress (0x02)
filterPolicy = UndirectedAdsOnly (0x00)
```

My settings for the `LESetScanEnable` are:

```
scanEnable = true (0x01)
filterDuplicates = true (0x01)
```

Debug output (note that for debugging purposes, the state machine currently transitions to `Critical` instead of `Error` upon problems):

```
Uninitialized -> Serial setup
Serial setup -> Clock synchronisation
Clock synchronisation -> SD setup
SD setup -> Initialized
Initialized -> Dispatch GapDeviceInit
Send: 01:00:fe:26#0805000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Dispatch GapDeviceInit -> Await GapDeviceInit HciExtCommandStatus
Receive: 04:ff:06#7f060000fe00
HciExtCommandStatus parameters: vendorEvent=0x067f, eventStatus=0x00, opcode=0xfe00
Await GapDeviceInit HciExtCommandStatus -> Await GapDeviceInitDone
Receive: 04:ff:2c#000600610a7b4c99b41b0004030000000000000000000000000000006c95ae6da27e123b450f5430f1bf13c7
GapDeviceInitDone parameters: eventStatus=0x00, ...
Await GapDeviceInitDone -> Dispatch SetEventMask
Send: 01:01:0c:08#0000000000000020
Dispatch SetEventMask -> Await SetEventMask CommandComplete
Receive: 04:0e:04#01010c00
CommandStatus parameters: numCommands=0x01, opcode=0x0c01, cmdStatus=0x00
Await SetEventMask CommandComplete -> Dispatch LESetEventMask
Send: 01:01:20:08#0200000000000000
Dispatch LESetEventMask -> Await LESetEventMask CommandComplete
Receive: 04:0e:04#01012000
CommandStatus parameters: numCommands=0x01, opcode=0x2001, cmdStatus=0x00
Await LESetEventMask CommandComplete -> Dispatch LESetScanParameters
Send: 01:0b:20:07#00100010000200
Dispatch LESetScanParameters -> Await LESetScanParameters CommandComplete
Await LESetScanParameters CommandComplete -> Critical: Timeout error (Last HCI message: Header incomplete)
Buffer contents discarded (numBytes=0x00):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely due to a hardware fault in the RedBearLabs BLEMini, I was forced to switch hardware to the Raspberry Pi 3. The program now works as a `systemd` service.